# Android RealmBaseAdapter with Listfragment

Tags: android, realm

I have a ListFragment with custom adapter which should extend from RealmBaseAdapter, implements ListAdapter in order to refresh the view if anything is changed. I query a user from the Realm, and get his/her friends which returns a RealmList

```
RealmList<User> users =realm.where(User.class).equalTo("id",userid).findFirst().getFriends()
```

This query return a RealmList as I store it in my User class this way:

```
public class User extends RealmObject implements Serializable {
@PrimaryKey
private long id;
private RealmList<User> friends = new RealmList<>();
```

So i can't do this, because the RealmBaseAdapter, needs a realmResult:

```
MySportmateListAdapter adapter = new MySportmateListAdapter(getContext(), users);
```

Can you help me, what is the solution for this?
In the user I think it is impossible to change the RealmList to RealmResults, am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three roads you can go:

1. Create your own ArrayAdapter and add OnChangeListener to the Realm instance, and call `notifyDataSetChange()` on each change.
2. If each User contains all its' friends in RealmList friends then you can use this query: `realm.where(User.class).equalTo("friends.id", userId).findAll()`. It will find all users which have User with id **userId** in their friends RealmList.
3. Obtain a friends list by creating a query by combining all the friends ids:

   ```
   RealmList<User> friends = realm.where(User.class).equalTo("id", userid).findFirst().getFriends()

   RealmQuery<User> query = realm.where(User.class);

   for(User friend : friends) {
       query = query.or().equalTo("friends.id", friend.getId());
   }

   RealmResults<User> results = query.findAll();
   ```

Comment: First thank you for your answer!
1. I tried this, but maybe i do something in the wrong way, because the visible rows didn't refreshed, but if i scroll down and back they had the new values.
2. Not possible for me, because not all user has their friends at the mobile database.

3. It is the right solution for me, BUT i think i have to write 
query = query.or().equalTo("id",friend.getId()); inside the for!
Thanks again :)

Comment: Cool. Regarding the 3rd variant: maybe I dind't understand you correctly, but `query = query.or().equalTo("friends.id", friend.getId());` is in for-loop in my code example.